# How to display image in Sharepoint List from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, power-automate

I have the following problem when I want to display an image in a column of type "Hyperlink or Picture" of Sharepoint List, the image comes from a column in a SQL Server table of data type "Image". To give more context to the problem that I am presenting, I will explain the process in detail.

I have an application developed in PowerApps which is connected to SQL Server, this application stores information in a table and among that information that I save is an image, which is the one I mentioned above and I save in the SQL Server table.

As I mentioned, the image is saved in an "Image" data type with the following information `"0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010101004800480000FFE…"` something like that, since the information chain is very long, I do not add it completely.

In the same application I have a display screen of the image which I can see without any problem after saving the record.

In addition to this application, I have a workflow developed with Power Automate which is a scheduled flow that runs at a certain time of the day. What this flow does is get the rows from my table in SQL Server and then create an element in a Sharepoint list, I do this to export the information from SQL Server to a Sharepoint list.

Among that information that I export, the "Image" column does not appear, as I show it in the flow below.

[image]

For this reason after the flow ends, I go to the Sharepoint list and the image is not stored.

[image]

It is for this reason that I request help to correctly display the image from SQL Server in the Sharepoint list.

- Is there something wrong that I'm doing in my workflow in Power
  Automate?
- Why is the image not displayed in the Sharepoint list?
- Any other solution to store the image and then be displayed correctly
  in    the Sharepoint list?
- Or do you think I have to change the data type with which I am
  storing the image in the SQL Server table?

**Conditions to take into account.**

It is not possible to connect the PowerApps application to the Sharepoint list directly, since the SQL Server table will be used by other external applications and that information is required to be in a SQL Server table.

**Update 1:**

I am currently getting an error when running the flow.

The error is in a particular record and it is in one of the records which has an image in SQL Server, this image must be stored in the Sharepoin list. But the flow throws the following error:

```
OpenApiOperationParameterTypeConversionFailed. The 'inputs.parameters' of workflow operation 'Create_item' of type 'OpenApiConnection' is not valid. Error details: Input parameter 'item/Image' is required to be of type 'String/uri'.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with PowerApps, hence the comment, but, does PowerApps has any custom code you can share in your question? - also, if you check in the browser, what value does have the "image" field - I believe the image is not converted back to an actual image and then cannot be rendered in the browser...

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Reviewing the outputs of the flow, the image shows it to me encoded in Base64, any additional suggestion to be able to visualize it in the Sharepoint list?

Comment: does the base64 string is well written in the "img" tag? - can you open (the base64 string) in a new tab?